# How to run github actions sequentially

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm attempting to execute the same GitHub operations in a sequential order, so every build will have an action run, but it should function so that the previous action is finished before the next build begins.

Something like this but without the extra package import
https://github.com/marketplace/actions/consecutive-workflow-action

https://github.com/fountainhead/action-wait-for-check

https://github.com/lewagon/wait-on-check-action

Answer (score 4):

You can have a look at the GitHub Actions keyword [needs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds) and the [workflow_run](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run) event. Also have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63148639/create-dependencies-between-jobs-in-github-actions) here.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).